# NCalc evaluation is wrong?

Tags: vb.net, math, expression, ncalc

I am trying to evaluate the following expression:

```
7088.800/(((((((24.65995+24.43061+24.54517+24.65192)/4)-32.0)*5/9)+273.15)/288.15)^.5)
```

If you are asking yourself why I didn't use Sqrt() instead of ^0.5 it's because I'm doing some things with the string beforehand that require there be no letters.

I am using this simple code:

```
Expression.CacheEnabled = False
x = New Expression(xEquation)
y = New Expression(yEquation)
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(x.Error)
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(y.Error)
Return New PointF(x.Evaluate, y.Evaluate)
```

The answer I get is: `7088.800`

The correct answer is:`7336.46922305`(according to google)

I am using .net 3.5 and ncalc 1.3.8

I suspect it doesn't like the amount of brackets there are but I can't find any mention of that being a problem anywhere...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot get Ncalc or Ncalc-edge (v1.4.1) to use the exponentiation operator `^` and produce the correct result. E.g., "4 ^ 2" gives 6. It does not accept `**` as an operator.

A little bit of investigation shows that it uses `^` as the `Xor` operator, in the style of C#. C# does not have an exponentiation operator, so you will have to devise a way of parsing your actual input string and using `Sqrt`.

There <strike>are currently</strike> were some requests on the Ncalc discussion forum regarding this, such as [Override ^ operator](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/discussions/652009) (link now dead, and it's not even available on the Wayback Machine).